# Correct syntax for writing WHILE loop in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures

With mysql-5.7.30 it seems that the following loop syntax is invalid.

```
mysql> SET @r = 6
    -> SET @i = 3
    -> WHILE @i <= @r DO
    -> BEGIN
    ->    PRINT @i
    -> END WHILE;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @i = 3
WHILE @i <= @r DO
BEGIN
   PRINT @i
END WHILE' at line 2
mysql>
```

I see various formats, e.g. `WHILE i <= r DO` and it seems that different versions, have minor syntax differences. How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

I even created a procedure according to the answer as below but as you can see it fails.

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 4
    -> DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 3
    -> WHILE i <= r DO
    -> SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE id=i
    -> END WHILE
    -> END;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 3
WHILE i <= r DO
SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE id=i
mysql>
```

UPDATE:

With the [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) about delimiter, I wrote the following code but got an error at the end.

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 4;
    -> DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 3;
    -> WHILE i <= r DO
    -> SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE id=i;
    -> END WHILE;
    -> END //
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'moodleuser'@'localhost' to database 'moodle'
```

UPDATE:

The following code is also wrong.

```
$ mysql -u moodleuser -p moodle
Enter password:
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 4;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semi-colons at the end of each statement. Also, you need to increment `i` in between each iteration (otherwise it's a infinite loop).

Consider:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
    DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 4;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 3;
    WHILE i <= r DO
        SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE id = i;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @mahmood: this code compiles fine on MySQL 5.,7, as you can see [in this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eQVbDDhQFUHxKJ2Pes3gQJ/0). Please run the code exactly as provided (I just added `DELIMITER` statements, that you seem to be missing).

Comment: Please see the picture at https://pasteboard.co/JeCvTrR.png I think there is problem with database. However, when I run the select query for an id alone, there is no problem.

Comment: @mahmood: this has nothing to do with the question you have asked, and with code I provided you... I can only recommend accepting the answer you found most helpful, and ask a new question if you have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Flow control statements like `WHILE` can be used in stored programs. Also `BEGIN` in `WHILE` and `PRINT` are used in SQL Server / Sybase, not in MySQL.

See documentation for [WHILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html)

Comment: Even with that document, my try with `DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 6;` fails with error in syntax. So, I am confused about the syntax.

Comment: Did you try the `DECLARE` directly or in a stored procedure?

Comment: You need change the `DELIMITER` and use semicolon's at the end of statements.

Comment: Excuse me, I tried but failed... Please see the updated post again.

Comment: `'moodleuser'@'localhost'` is missing `CREATE ROUTINE` permission to the moodle-database. And you need to increase the `i` variable inside the `WHILE` to avoid infinite loop).

Comment: So, how can I change the permission?

Comment: Use the `GRANT` command. See documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges